# Homework for school not working spams or just dont work

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

```
name = input ("Enter name :")
gender = input("are you a m/M or a f/F:")
while gender != 'M' or gender != 'm' or gender != 'f' or gender != 'F':
    if gender in ['M', 'm']:
        print("Hello Mr",name,",")
if gender in ['F', 'f']:
    print("Hello Miss",name,",")
```

cant seem to fix it if I do M or m it spams Hello Mr (name) tried it with female just dont do anything

Comment: Hint: `gender != 'M' or gender != 'm' or gender != 'f' or gender != 'F'` is always true.

Comment: Hint2: 6th line is not indented properly.

Comment: condition is always True because `gender` will be at least different of 3 of the 4 letters

Comment: I dont get it can you please explain in baby words

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the gender is `m` for example, then the condition `while gender != 'M' or gender != 'm' or gender != 'f' or gender != 'F':`  is always True so it'll execute the code below the while block infinite times.
**In fact you don't even need the while statement for this program.**

```
gender = input("are you a m/M or a f/F:")
if gender in ['M', 'm']:
    print("Hello Mr",name,",")
if gender in ['F', 'f']:
    print("Hello Miss",name,",")
```

I could have used if-elif-else construct as well.

```
name = input ("Enter name :")
gender = input("are you a m/M or a f/F:")
if gender in ['M', 'm']:
    print("Hello Mr",name,",")
elif gender in ['F', 'f']:
    print("Hello Miss",name,",")
else:
    print("Invalid Input")
```

If you want the program to ask for gender until the user specifies no then the following program should do the trick:

```
choice=1
while choice==1:
    name = input ("Enter name :")
    gender = input("are you a m/M or a f/F:")
    if gender in ['M', 'm']:
        print("Hello Mr",name,",")
    elif gender in ['F', 'f']:
        print("Hello Miss",name,",")
    else:
        print("Invalid Input")
    choice=int(input("Enter 1 if you want to greet another person otherwise enter 0"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for something like this?
It allows you to give inputs two times and print the output. You can change the condition to give more inputs than 2.

```
i = 0
while i <2:
    name = input ("Enter name :")
    gender = input("are you a m/M or a f/F:")
    if gender in ['M', 'm']:
        print("Hello Mr",name,",")
    elif gender in ['F', 'f']:
        print("Hello Miss",name,",")
    i += 1
```